# Adding a recurring hangfire job to an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, hangfire

I installed Hangfire successfully to my ASP.NET Core MVC application. I see that it added all of the tables to my database and I am able to access the Dashboard.

I need to figure out where in my code I should place the Hangfire code for a recurring job that will run every 30 minutes. Basically, every 30 minutes call

```
 _notificationRepository.GetNotifications()
         .Where(n => n.NotificationDate = DateTime.Now() 
            && n.CreatedBy == currentLoggedInUser)
```

Comment: You always can make ajax call from client

Comment: The Hangfire documentation is absolutely superb - here's the section on [recurring tasks](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html)

Comment: @RB I read through that page and I know how to setup a recurring task. My question is where to set it up inside the site. I want it to become active as soon as the site is active.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Wherever you do the rest of your site configuration (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration) - although you'll have to clarify what you mean by "as soon as the site is active" - when *precisely* do you want the job to be configured?

Comment: @RB I believe in an ASP.NET Core application it would go in the Main of Program.cs. Does this make sense? I want the job to start running exactly when the site starts, if I hit Debug in VS

Comment: @BlakeRivell Well, it depends on how you are hosting your web-site. If it's self-hosted, then that would be a place you *could* do it, whereas if it was run through IIS, you wouldn't even have a `Main` method. I would recommend doing it in ASP.NET configuration as per my link, as then it doesn't matter how you are hosting your web-site...

Comment: @RB One final thing, I now have the job setup in my Startup.cs file in the constructor. Lets say each time the job runs it queries and gets the notifications. Do you know how I would then pass these notifications off to something like SignalR to get them to the client?

Comment: @BlakeRivell Please raise another question, showing what you have tried - it's the preferred approach on Stack Overflow :)